# NodeJs : how to resolve Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.xx:xxxx

Tags: mysql, node.js, error-handling

How to handle error connect with nodejs.

In my case server throws error after certain time limit.

//Code

```
const app       =     require("express");
const mysql     =     require("mysql");
const http      =     require('http').Server(app);
const io        =     require("socket.io")(http);
var moment = require('moment'); 
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const req = https.request(options, callback)

const Tgfancy = require("tgfancy");

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "xxxxxx"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    setInterval(function() {
    //My code
   });
});
```

What modification should i do to handle my error connection of ETIMEDOUT.
Any suggestion would be very much helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you can retry if it takes longtime.

```
 function connnectSQL(){
     con.connect(function (err) {
         if (err) {
             setImmediate(connnectSQL, 500)
            //  or
            // process.nextTick(connnectSQL)
         }

         setInterval(function () {
             //My code
         });
     });

 }
```

Comment: are you calling connnectSQL() function

Comment: use same as you defined here.